# Find all neighbors within specified distance of each element in 2-D Array

Tags: matlab, image-processing, multidimensional-array

I would like to implement Adaptive watershed segmentation using Matlab.

One step in this algorithm is :

Scan the marker map pixel by pixel. If M(x0,y0) is 1, seek the spurious maxima in its neighbourhood with a radius of D(x ,y ).

D and M are all 2-D array.

Is there any function can Find all neighbors within specified distance of each element in 2-D Array?

I couldn't use the rangesearch() so I don't know dose it can solve my problem.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, rengesearch is definitely the best way to solve this problem.
However, since you don't have Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox, you can try using MATLAB's bwdist function.

bwdist function is basically a distance transform, and it can also return a map of distances from a certain point.
The second parameter of bwdist defines the type of distance function to use (The default distance function is Euclidean).

Example:

```
%inputMat is the original matrix
inputMat = ones(10,10);
%(Px,Py) is the point to calculate the distance from
Px = 5; Py = 5;

%calls bwdist
tempMat = false(size(inputMat));
tempMat(Py,Px) = true;
distMat = bwdist(tempMat);

%search for neighbour pixels 
neigbourPixels = distMat < D(Px,Py);
[Y, X] = ind2sub(size(neigbourPixels),find(neigbourPixels));

%prints result
[Y,X]
```

result:

```
ans =

 4     4
 5     4
 6     4
 4     5
 5     5
 6     5
 4     6
 5     6
 6     6
```

**Runtime optimization**

The downside of this method is that the computation time of bwdist may be slow if you call it many times. Therefore, if the runtime is important, I suggest the following optimization:

First stage:

Calculate the distance map only once, on a big matrix as follows:

```
N = max(size(inputMat)); 
tempMat = false(N,N);
tempMat(N/2,N/2) = true;
distMatInitial = bwdist(tempMat);
```

Second stage:

Given a new point (Px,Py) which you want to find its neigbours, calculate its distance map without calling to bwdist again, by simply copying a patch from the center of distMatInitial:

```
Mp = 30; %determines maximal patch size
distsMapFromPxPy = zeros(size(inputMat));
distsMapFromPxPy(Py-Mp:Py+Mp,Px-Mp:Px+Mp) = distMatInitial(N/2-Mp,N/2+Mp,N/2-Mp:N/2+Mp);
```

*Notice that this example doesn't handle edge cases such as:

```
(1)(Py-Mp)<0 (2)(Py+Mp)>m (3)(Px-Mp)<0 (4)(Px+Mp)>n
```

Therefore, if you choose to try this approach, don't forget to handle these cases.